# Content not getting displayed on my social media site project when using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to build a Social Media webiste as a major project and I tried using Ajax today, but content is not getting displayed after implementing it. I'm trying to load posts with limit kept at 10 but the content is just not getting displayed on index.

```
enter code herepublic function loadPostsFriends($data,$limit)
{
    $page=$data['page'];
    $userLoggedIn=$this->user_obj->getUsername();
    if($page==1)
    {
        $start=0;
    }
    else
    {
        $start=($page-1) * $limit;   
    }
    $str=""; //Str to return
    $data_query=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data_query) > 0)
    {
    $num_iterations = 0; //number of result checking
    $count=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data_query))
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $body=$row['body'];
        $added_by=$row['added_by'];
        $date_time=$row['date_added'];
        //prepare user_to string to include it even if not posted to an user
        if($row['user_to'] == 'none')
        {
            $user_to="";
        }
        else
        {
           $user_to_obj=new User($con,$row['user_to']);
           $user_to_name=$user_to_obj->getFirstAndLastName();
           $user_to="wrote to <a href'" . $row['user_to'] . "'>" . $user_to_name . "</a>";
        }
        //check if userwho posted has their account closed
        $added_by_obj=new User($this->con,$added_by);
        if($added_by_obj->isClosed())
        {
            continue;
        }
        if($num_iterations++ < $start)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //once 10 posts loaded just break
        if($count > $limit)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $count++;    
        }
var userLoggedIn='<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#loading').show();
    //ajax request for loading 1st posts
    $.ajax({
       url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
       cache:false,
       success: function(data)
        {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('.posts_area').html(data);
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
     var height=$('.posts_area').height(); //div containing posts
     var scroll_top=$(this).scrollTop();
     var page=$('.post_area').find('.nextPage').val();
     var noMorePosts=$('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();
     if((document.body.scrollHeight==document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false')
         {
            $('#loading').show();
            var ajaxReq=$.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
            cache:false,
            success: function(response)
            {
             $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //removes current next page
             $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove();
             $("#loading").hide();
             $('.posts_area').append(response);
            }
          });
         } //If end
        return false;
    }); //ending of $(window).scroll(function()
});
```

PS: Added some mode code of displaying the content to better understand my problem.

Comment: This seems incomplete (at the very least you haven't closed the function with a `}`, so that makes me think there should be more). Also, as you're talking about Ajax, you really should show the javascript which will be handling the posting and receiving the results.

Comment: I just added those code. There is no error with syntax. I just can't seem to extract data from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're new here. Welcome. It's a bit hard when you don't post your **code** fully as others may have a hard time understanding it. So please do post it fully next time.

Solution to displaying data using Ajax?

PHP code:

```
  $data = array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data_query)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $body=$row['body'];
    $data[] = $id;
    $data[] = $body;
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
```

Save the data to a data array variable. Then return it in json format using **json_encode**.

JS code:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'url/to/server',
  method: 'get',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    //data is returned from php script
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log("error");
  }
})
```

I hope it helps.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sir! Yes I'm new here and will try better next time. I've edited the post with more code for better understanding my problem. I tried your solution but same result nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: You have to echo it from PHP code, you're not returning anything, hence it doesn't get displayed.

Comment: Look at the network tab from your browser, is the ajax getting fired?